# ORing where condition in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM   ptsurvey.survey    s
    WHERE (s.companyid = 1 AND s.groupid = 34   AND s.status=1  AND s.creatoruid =286)
      OR
        (AND s.groupid = 34  AND s.status=2 AND s.status = 1));
```

i want to check a condition like this in mysql . This query is not working.

Comment: Your should format source code with the `{}` toolbar button. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: "Not working" is the worse possible piece of info you could provide, esp. if you are actually getting a precise error message from MySQL with numeric code and all.

Answer (score 3):

get rid of the extra "AND" and close paren...

```
SELECT * 
   FROM   
      ptsurvey.survey s
   WHERE 
         (     s.companyid = 1 
           AND s.groupid = 34   
           AND s.status = 1  
           AND s.creatoruid = 286 )
      OR 
         (     s.groupid = 34  
           AND s.status=2 
           AND s.status = 1);
```

Additionally, your second clause portion (the OR ) side, you are testing for BOTH s.Status = 2 AND s.Status = 1 which will NEVER be true... I think you meant for only 1 status to be tested for this element.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL you need to close as many parenthesis as you open (not less, not more).

Comment: i closed all the braces that i opened still its not working. i think the query is wrong.

Comment: @kiran: Then why am I seeing one more closing parenthesis than there are opening? I would also like to add that the latter part of the WHERE clause will never be true.

Comment: actually i want to pic status 1 ,2, 3 if creatoruid = database uid , otherwise i want to pic status=1  ... any solution